# How to make files from FILE{1-3} variables value in for loop?

Tags: bash

I have some files, like:

```
FILE1="apple.txt"
FILE2="grapes.txt"
FILE3="strawberry.txt"
```

How can I make these files in bash?

I tried this, but I got an error...

```
for f in {1..3}
do
    echo hello > $(FILE$f)
done
```

Errors:

```
./make_files.sh: line 48: FILE1: command not found
./make_files.sh: line 48: $(FILE$f): ambiguous redirect
```

I need 3 txts, apple, grapes and strawberry which are contains hello.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want do is to create the files with the three name:
apple.txt , grapes.txt and strawberry.txt

so you should do:

```
for f in {1..3}
do
    TMP="FILE$f"
    echo hello > "${!TMP}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want this:

```
for f in {1..3}
do
    echo hello > FILE"$f"
done
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment to another answer I think you really want this:

```
for f in {1..3}
do
    echo hello > $(< FILE"$f")
done
```

Example:

```
$ ls
FILE1  FILE2  FILE3
$ cat FILE1 FILE2 FILE3
apple.txt
grapes.txt
strawberry.txt
$ for f in {1..3}
> do
>     echo hello > $(< FILE"$f")
> done
$ cat apple.txt  grapes.txt  strawberry.txt
hello
hello
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Or do it all at once:

```
for f in FILE{1..3}; do
  echo hello >"${!f}"
done
```

The main error in your code was the`$(`...`)`, which is command substitution: it was trying to *run* the names`FILE1`, `FILE2`, etc. *as commands* in order to use *the output of those commands* as the names of the files to write.

What you want to do instead is use those as parameter names. To indirectly retrieve the value of a parameter whose name is stored in another parameter, you use `!`, as in `${!f}`.

But most of the time when you're doing something like this you're better off using an array:

```
FILES=("apple.txt" "grapes.txt" "strawberry.txt")
for f in "${FILES[@]}"; do
  echo hello >"$f"
done
```

Comment: It writes out hello, to FILE1, FILE2, FILE3. But I need to write out hello to apple.txt, etc..